# Counting no of parameters in a SOAP Operation

Tags: xml, web-services, wcf, soap, xpath

Below is Body of a SOAP Message (of a WCF service)-

```
<s:Body>
<Multiply xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<x xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:L>4</a:L>
<a:M>3</a:M>
</x>
<y xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:L>-2</a:L>
<a:M>2</a:M>
</y>
</Multiply>
</s:Body>
```

In the above, operation Multiply has two argument of the same type: x & y. The CService has other operation just has one parameter of the same type (same as x or y).

I've define a namespace table as

```
<namespaceTable>
          <add prefix="o" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
</namespaceTable>
```

Now I want to define filters using XPath to determine whether any operation has parameters count one or two to route the messages accordingly like below-

```
 <filters>
          <filter name="one" filterType="XPath" filterData="//o:Count > 1" />
          <filter name="two" filterType="XPath" filterData="//o:Count = 1" />
 </filters>
```

But I'm not able to find any solution. is there any way to count the no of parameters in soap operation?

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is incorrect, if I understand you!

I think you want to count that `Multiply` has two children i.e. `x` and `y`? If so then you just need to count the children of `Multiply` that are in the namespace `http://tempuri.org/`

e.g. `count(//o:Multiply/child::o:*)`

```
<filters>
    <filter name="one" filterType="XPath" filterData="count(//o:Multiply/child::o:*) gt 1" />
    <filter name="two" filterType="XPath" filterData="count(//o:Multiply/child::o:*) eq 1" />
</filters>
```